# Как перенести несколько строк после for в одну на питоне без print

Tags: python, строки, циклы, бот

Я только учусь, так что код может быть ужасным:)
Я хочу сделать телеграм бота на питоне и там будет функция генерации паролей, но есть одна проблемка - бот отправляет юзеру каждый символ пароля в отдельном сообщении а нужно одним
Подскажите как починить

```py
def pass_gen(message):
    if int(leng) >= 1 and int(leng) <= 1000:
        for passwr in range(int(leng)):
            passwr = random.choice(LwrAndUppr_lettandDigits)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, passwr)
            bot.send_message(chat_id=000, text=passwr)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, place)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=000, text=place)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=000, text=message.from_user.id)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=000,text=message.from_user.first_name)
```

Comment: Сначала собери пароль, а потом уже send_message после цикла

Comment: Так у  вас отправка  сообщений стоит в цикле. Уберите отступы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять на такое:

```
def pass_gen(message):
    if int(leng) >= 1 and int(leng) <= 1000:
        passwr = ''.join(random.choice(LwrAndUppr_lettandDigits) for _ in range(int(leng))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, passwr)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=000, text=passwr)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, place)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=000, text=place)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=000, text=message.from_user.id)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=000,text=message.from_user.first_name)
```

Comment: О, класс, всё работает) Спасибо огромное)  Я часов 5 сидел не мог починить

Comment: @harley Ну, со временем наметаете глаз и будете сразу видеть, что в цикле выполняется, что без цикла, как данные собирать в список будете знать и т.д. )